# django update version without pip

Tags: django, installation, pip, upgrade

I want to update my django version (1.8 ->1.9).
My current version was installed using pip (`pip install Django)` .
Now I need to install a newer version **without** pip.
I think I should run from the django package folder, using the setup.py file:

```
python setup.py install
```

[I've installed some other packages using a setup.py file .]
The question - will that create some problems? And, does the setup.py install method take care for uninstalling the older version? Or I have to uninstall manually somehow?
I don't have internet connection in this computer, so no pip.

Answer (score 2):

Download a release (they are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/releases)), and copy to your computer.

Then use `pip install` to install the archive. For example

```
pip install django-1.9.3.tar.gz
```

For more ways to use `pip install`, see [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples).

Comment: I totally agree to this answer, using pip is the best way... But he wrote to not use pip...

Comment: The OP said without pip, but that's because they don't have internet access on that computer. That means that `pip install django` won't work, but my answer should still work.

Comment: Indeed, if I can use pip without Internet,  so pip is fine. Never used it like that with tar, always used to download from the internet. Is that will work on windows too?

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows, give it a try!